# How can I install putty on freya?

Tags: software-installation

I am a Windows user.  And recently started using freya for learning.  I need to install and configure putty for the SSH. I am not sure how to download and install it. Is there any command I have to run in terminal?.

Comment: Why would you need ssh emulator on a linux box is beyond me....

Comment: Because I need to connect my ubuntu vps with ssh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install from Terminal**

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install putty
```

**Now Access the Putty SSH Client**

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Thank it worked.  It just similar to ubuntu.  Nothing difference in it.

Comment: yes, it is.  :)..

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, elementary comes with an SSH client (as do most flavors of Linux). You can start an SSH session by opening Terminal and running the following command:

`ssh your-username@name-of-server.com`

Comment: I have not tested it directly.  Will it connect the vps ubuntu.?

Comment: Yep, it should connect to just about any Linux server. I've used this command in the past on elementary to connect to a Linux VPS running CentOS. It worked like a charm.